# Negative values of Lab color space in histogram

Tags: matlab, image-processing, histogram, lab-color-space

I am using this [RGB2Lab](https://github.com/yaoliUoA/evalsaliency/blob/master/edison_matlab_interface/RGB2Lab.m) code to convert my RGB image to Lab image.Naturally,there are some negative values in lab color image.
When I try to plot histogram of lab image channels negative pixel values are ignored and I am only getting the histogram in 0-255 range.But it is stated in link that range of L 0-100 , a and b is -110 to 110. How can I get lab color space histogram correctly ?

*UPDATE : Anders answer is nice,that was something similar to answer I expected.In his solution , the `histogram` function opens a figure to show histogram which make it slower in the case of calculating histogram of each frame of the video.*

Comment: hum? What function are you using for the histogram?

Comment: I dont understand. Then the `hist` fucntion does the job....

Comment: Or possibly [histcounts](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts.html)

Comment: Can you update your answer with histcounts so that I can accept for future viewers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not happen. You are probably using a wrong function.

Look at the example of how to make an histogram

```
% Create data from -100 to 1000
data=rand(1000,1)*200-100;
```

If you are using a version of MATLAB before 2014b then

```
hist(data);
```

if it is newer then

```
histogram(data);
```

This will output:

[image]

As you see, the values in the histogram go from -100 to 100, the range of the data.

If you don't want to plot anything, then use the `hist` version, and get the counts and centers by doing `[count,center]=hist(data)`.

Comment: Thank Ander, I need what is more than this. histogram function is returning a handle to plot of a histogram where Values are stored as a field.Also everytime this function is called,it is opening plot of the histogram which make it very slow in my case as I need to calculate histogram of thousands of Lab images.Do you have any other reccomendation ?

Comment: @MuhammetAliAsan Update your question with all the information of the problem you wnat to solve!

Comment: @MuhammetAliAsan is there anything my answer is missing?